# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have a model method that I'd like to call from various controllers. It looks something like this:

```
def Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def read!
      self.read_at = Time.now
      self.save
      self.thread.status = Status.find_by_name("read")
      self.thread.save
    end
end
```

In my controller, if I call `@post.read!`, will this rollback on any errors?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your current setup, if read_at gives an error, it will still continue onto the code that executes `thread.status` for example.

You want to use [ActiveRecord transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```ruby
def read!
  transaction do
    self.read_at = Time.now
    self.save
    self.thread.status = Status.find_by_name("read")
    self.thread.save
  end
end
```

By using transactions, you can be assured that either all your database calls(within the transaction block) will be persisted to the database, or none at all.

Comment: `transaction` is also defined as an instance method in the `ActiveRecord` class, so you can also call it directly (without prefixing `ActiveRecord::Base`).

Comment: Wouldn't `save!` be better than `save`? I think, if the second `save` fails, no exception is thrown, therefore the transaction is not rolled back and the thread and post end up out of sync with each other.

Comment: as @antinome says, you definitely want to use save! in your transactions otherwise there is no point.. see [this post](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/#transaction_rollback_triggers) about when transaction rollbacks are triggered