# Adding records to multiple models in one transaction during create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

I have the following new and create actions.  They are used to create a new account in a multi-tenant app.  It works fine but even as a newbie I know this is not correct.  Here is my question, how can I make the create action more thin so it follows best practices?  And, how can I make so that all the queries submit under one transaction?

Here are my methods:

```
  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @user = @account.users.build()
    @account.accounts_users.build()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @account }
    end
  end



  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
         @user = User.find_by_email(params[:account][:users_attributes]["0"][:email])
        Profile.create(:user_id => @user.id)
        @group = @account.groups.create(:name => 'Default', :user_id => @user)
        @group.members.create(:account_id => @account, :user_id => @user)
        Role.all.each do |role|
          @user.roles_users.create(:role_id => role.id, :account_id => @account)
        end

        flash[:domain] = @account.subdomain
        format.html { redirect_to thanks_url }
        format.json { render json: @account, status: :created, location: @account }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My models are:

- Account (has_many :users; :through account_users)
- User (has_one :profile)
- Accounts_User (belongs_to :account; belongs_to :user)
- Group (has_many :members, as: membership; belongs_to :user)
- Member (belongs_to :membership, :polymorphic => true)
- Profile (belongs_to :user)
- Roles (has_many :roles_users; has_many :users :through => :roles_users; has_many :accounts, :through => :roles_users)
- RolesUser (belongs_to :user; belongs_to :account; belongs_to :role)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, grouping all of your statements in `create` controller in a transaction block will be a good idea. Check [ActiveRecord Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) documentation to learn more about it. An example can be found at [Rails 3 ActiveRecord Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560731/rails-3-activerecord-transactions).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  The links provided me with enough information to get going.  I am having some problems with my transaction but decided to create a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787658/rails-transaction-doesnt-input-correct-data).  If you have any insight, I'd appreciate your input.